# ScanCallback: Check if no device has been found in a certain intervall

Tags: kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I built an app that is constantly checking for a BLE device and on onScanResult updates a list with the newly discovered device.

I want to delete the devices in the list if no device was found in a certain interval. Is there an elegant way to get a callback if this was the case (I am trying to avoid some nasty work-around)? In the documentation on *developer.android.com* I haven't found something like that. The method:

```
    private val leScanCallback: ScanCallback = object : ScanCallback() {
    override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult) {
        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
        val device = result.device
        Log.d("LeDeviceScanner", "Device found: ${device.address} - ${device.name ?: "Unknown"}")
        onDeviceResult(result.device)
    }
}
```

Other callbacks are as far as I see: *onScanFailed* and *onBatchScanResults* and none of those would help me.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question which hopefully will help somebody. **There is no simple callback for not finding a device**. So there has to be found a work-around.
In my case I stored found devices in a list and wanted to delete the device If it has not been found again in a minute of searching. I did it with a timestamp I passed back every time a device was found. Not as elegant, but it worked.